# Apache tomcat equivalent of apachectl graceful

Tags: tomcat

On a basic LAMP stack, at least with our RHEL5/6 servers, we are able to apply rolling code-updates to our document management system across load-balanced web servers without killing users' connections (and possibly document downloads) by using `apachectl graceful` and `apachectl graceful-stop`.  We're migrating to a Tomcat web server based application, and we'd like to have that sort of capability with our new system, but I cannot find any sort of equivalent functionality with tomcat6.  Does such a capability exist with tomcat6?

Comment: @sandroid: Please don't use lmgtfy links, they are very condescending and considered rude around here. Instead, explain it and maybe link to the result of lmgtfy for more information.

Comment: @Sven couldn't edit... Scott, a quick search for "Tomcat Restart Graceful" gives this as the first hit: http://www.tomcatexpert.com/ask-the-experts/how-do-you-gracefully-restart-tomcat  This confirms you can't find what you're looking for but more importantly provides a workaround you may be able to use.

Comment: I don't understand why the question is being voted down, if you have a high traffic web site, and your tomcat takes 30 secs to reboot, then its not very nice serving 404/500 errors for that time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature for Tomcat.

Remember that Tomcat is an application server and not a web server and it needs to load things upon start and perhaps shut down things nicely upon shutdown.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  It makes sense... Unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

*Short Answer*

If you have load balanced tomcat instances and your load balancer supports sticky sessions and live configuration, then the you can achieve the kind of rolling and transparent upgrades that you are talking about (to some degree) by rotating out the tomcat instances 1 by 1.

*Long(er) Answer*

With respect to the other answers correct description of tomcat as an application server vs httpd and the associated issues there are actually a number of ways to get what you want, which is an end-user transparent restart.

Given that tomcat frequently takes 30 seconds or more depending on how monstrous and bloated your application is to deploy from cold, it is usually useful to be able to do it transparently.

An additional bonus of this method I will explain is that it is reassuring to be able to check the new application in production before putting it live to your customers.

***So...*** apache's [graceful restart](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/stopping.html#graceful) advises its children to exit after their current request has completed, and replaces them with new spawned processes/threads that have re-read the new configuration file. Hence long running connections can finish downloading while new requests get the new content. There are effectively 2 versions of the application running during the graceful restart transition managed by apache, the old and the new.

Unfortunately, [with tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html#Deploying_on_a_running_Tomcat_server) if autodeploy=true is set, any change to the configuration files or war contents causes a rather ungraceful redeployment of the Context and I would guess the Catalina web container waits for some specified time, before killing all the outstanding threads and requests. It's not very transparent, and you end up serving horrible 500 errors until the app is back on its feet :-(

Hence to allow the transparent end-user experience you are going to need to have 2 versions of your app running at the same time for a short period, one for the old connections and one for the new. (There are a number of caveats to these approaches which I will cover below...)

The *simplest way*, is to have a front-end load balancer such as apache, haproxy, or Cisco CSM with 2 or more tomcat instances - where the load balancer supports sticky sessions and hot load balancer configuration deployment.

eg tomcat1, tomcat2 and balancer

1. change tomcat2 preference level in the server-farm in the load balancer to zero. (haproxy  definitely and I think mod_proxy allow you to change the instance preference live.)
2. wait until all connections are hitting tomcat1 (use jmx or netstat to monitor network connections)
3. redeploy web app on tomcat2
4. wait for tomcat2 to come up, sanity test the application yourself!
5. swap preference to tomcat2 to zero, and tomcat1 to high
6. wait until all the connections are on tomcat1,
7. do vice-versa. deploy other node, and repeat etc.

Notice that it is the *change* node preference level rather than, *drop* node will allow the load balancer to gracefully manage the transition of the connections to the new web app.

Obviously if you only have 1 server, and hence only 1 tomcat, you can come up with something similar, but this requires some clever naming for your webapp. I have never had to deploy into production on 1 tomcat, but I would do it with 2 versions of my web app with different war names and doc paths installed on the same tomcat6 like so;

```
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/mywebapp_0_1.war => http://localhost:8080/mywebapp_0_1
/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/mywebapp_0_2.war => http://localhost:8080/mywebapp_0_2
```

And make the change transparent by using apache mod_proxy or haproxy to migrate the connections between the 2 apps gracefully.

ie I would have apache httpd AND tomcat6 installed together on the same box, with httpd mod_proxy pointing like so;

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so

<Location /balancer-manager>
SetHandler balancer-manager
</Location>

<Proxy balancer://cluster>
BalancerMember http://localhost:8080/webapp_0_1
BalancerMember http://localhost:8080/webapp_0_2
</Proxy>

<Location />
ProxyPass balancer://cluster/webapp stickysession=JSESSIONID
</Location>
```

**Caveat**, if you have to upgrade your data base schemas, then unless you want to start doing some crazy naming and linking sh*t with your databases like database_0_1 then, you are going to have to suck up some downtime.

If your users have really long sessions, then tomcat6 supports [session clustering](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/cluster.html) using a variety of backends